Homer is bobbing his head and singing at a concert in what episode from The Simpsons?
In what episode does Homer go to some concert and sings along with the band, where he is bobbing his head back and forth saying "badabadaba badababadaba"?

You might be talking about this clip (sorry about the quality, it's the best I could find) from Kill the Alligator and Run (Season 11, Episode 19) where Homer attends a Kid Rock concert. He starts singing along in gibberish around 0:07:




I know about this episode but its not the one. The one I am talking about, its like Homer is in a trance and he's just bobbing his head back and forth chanting something.

Can't recall then, sorry. Many, many musician cameos on that show. Do you remember anything else?

@AasimAzam Maybe the one where he's on "Hullaballooza" (or however that's called) with the kids and gets a job as a freak on whom a cannon is fired?

@NapoleonWilson That's the episode that 1st sprang to my mind.  It is called Homerpalooza & the festival is Hullabalooza.

@NapoleonWilson But I just watched it again, and that is not it.  There is one scene in the car when he's describing 'rocking on' where he does a string of "yes, yes, yes." and "no, no, no.." (just to mix it up).  The scenes with him in the audience at Hullabalooza are very short. They consist of a few moments with Bart & Lisa arguing with him about the Rastafarian hat, then moving off.  After that, he is quickly identified as a narc. and crowd passed "more butt support, please!" to the outer limits and dumped on the ground.  Just seconds later, he sets off the pig blaster & is famous.

after further consideration and conferring with my brother, this is in fact the scene.
